# How to initialize an array when variable is placed into separate section (GNU ARM GCC)

Tags: gcc, linker, initialization, linker-scripts

I tried to initialize an array that is placed into a separate section. But had no success. Background story is that I want to emulate an external memory in an embedded system for some testing.

Initializing an array when it goes to `.data` works fine.

```
uint8_t some_data_not_in_mysection[4] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF }
```

gives me this, as expected:

```
[0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  |
0xDE | 0xAD | 0xBE | 0xEF |
```

When placing to a section like this:

```
uint8_t some_data_placed_in_mysection[4] __attribute__((__section__(".mysection"))) =
{
    0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD
};
```

I get:

```
[0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  |
0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | actual
```

but I expected this:

```
0xAA | 0xBB | 0xCC | 0xDD | expected
```

What I have tried so far:

I tried to force a variable to be initialized with the nocommon attribute.

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

> You may only use the section attribute with a fully initialized global definition because of the way linkers work. The linker requires each object be defined once, with the exception that uninitialized variables tentatively go in the common (or bss) section and can be multiply "defined". You can force a variable to be initialized with the -fno-common flag or the nocommon attribute.

So I tried with:

```
uint8_t some_data_placed_in_mysection[4] __attribute__((section(".mysection"), nocommon))
```

Had no success.

Also found this:
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/04/19/gnu-linker-can-you-not-initialize-my-variable/

with the topic: "GNU Linker, can you NOT Initialize my Variable?" with the (NOLAOD) linker attribute.
But that's exactly the opposite what I need.

Any hints?

---

I am using GNU ARM GCC (arm-none-eabi-gcc and linking with arm-none-eabi-g++)

N.B. Linker stuff:

```
.mysection :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __mysection_start__ = .;
    *(.mysection*)
    __mysection_end__ = .;
} > MY_MEMORY_REGION
```